# Generate variable length wordlist with ! character at the end?

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat, crunch

I am trying to create a variable length word list with crunch that guarantees a exclamation point (!) at the end of each word. I want a wordlist of all words of length 4 - 6, with the last character being an exclamation point and the rest being lower case letters. I'm then going to feed all of this into hashcat.

What command/crunch options would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you can not create a word-list of *variable word length* **and** *a fixed terminating character*. Be sure to denote a specific word library if you have one, I'm using the default in these examples.

You have two options:

1. Run Crunch 3 separate times, once for each word-length (*in total*) 4 alpha with an appended '!', 5 alphas with an appended '!', etc... Also note, you need to make sure you escape the exclamation with a backslash. You can also establish parameters on the word-list file size, or number of words compiled.

   ```
   ./crunch 5 5 -t @@@@/! -o filename.txt
   ./crunch 6 6 -t @@@@@/! -o filename.txt
   ./crunch 7 7 -t @@@@@@/! -o filename.txt
   ```

   Note the above word-lengths 5, 6 and 7. This corresponds to a word containing 4, 5 or 6 alphabetical characters, with an additional fixed special '!' character. The commands `./crunch 4 6` and/or `./crunch 3 5` will not create words of correct length.
2. Run one instance of Crunch to generate **only** the nonfixed characters,

   ```
   ./crunch 4 6 -o filename.txt
   ```

   Write a basic script to retroactively append the '!',

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Good idea to run three separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer. I think you can issue the following command:

```
./crunch 3 5 -f /usr/share/rainbowcrack/charset.txt loweralpha -o filename.txt
```

And then you run a bash script to append an exclamation mark at the end. I'm not all that good at bash scripting but:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch new-file.txt;
for line in $(cat filename.txt);do echo $line! >> new-file.txt;done
```

This will give you passwords (all lower case) between the length of 4-6 and ending with an exclamation mark.